# How is ContextLoaderListener from Spring being run even when web.xml does not include it?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-3.0, servletcontextlistener

I have a webapp I inherited from another team that uses spring.  I have been trying to debug some odd behavior and wanted to "turn off" any spring servlets/filters/context-listeners.

So I removed the entry in web.xml that looked like this...

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Yet somehow after a clean/build and run of our application I am hitting org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener on the method contextInitialized.

So my question is if my web.xml no longer declared ContextLoadListener as a listener to run how/why is it being run?  I looked and the source for Spring 3.2.3-RELEASE does not appear to have the Servlet 3.0 Annotation @WebServletContextListener.

So why/how is this Context Listener running?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any `WebApplicationInitializer` classes on your classpath?

Comment: Check if the dispatcher-servlet is loading any configuration.

Comment: Yes org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer. Actually two versions one which is 2.5.1 and another which is 2.22.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet 3.0 introduced [`ServletContainerInitializer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html)

> Interface which allows a library/runtime to be notified of a web
>   application's startup phase and perform any required programmatic
>   registration of servlets, filters, and listeners in response to it.

If you have the spring-web jar on your classpath, it implicitly registers its own implementation of this interface, [`SpringServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html). This in turn scans for implementations of [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) on the classpath.

You apparently have [`SpringWebApplicationInitializer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.8/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spring/SpringWebApplicationInitializer.html) which

> [...] initializes Spring context by adding a Spring
>   `ContextLoaderListener` to the `ServletContext`.

The `ContextLoaderListener` you see most likely comes from that.